# What does Character.isDigit return?

Tags: java

I found this example online. peek contains one character read from the buffered reader with `readch(br)`. The following cycle must continue until the read character is a number

```
while(Character.isDigit(peek) 
    && !Character.isLetter(peek) && peek != '_') {
    int n = (int) peek - 48;
    sum = sum*10 + n;
    readch(br);
}
```

Isn't it enough to just say `Character.isDigit`?

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to add link to the documentation of `isDigit` that *you* read? (Clearly it is not https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character#isDigit(int))

Comment: You can have a look at the [*documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) and check it your-self before asking. If you've done this, than what the issue you're having?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's redundant. [`Character.isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) returns true if the character type (from `Character.getType`) is `DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER`, and [`Character.isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) returns true if the same type is one of several categories (`DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER` is not one of the categories listed).

[`getType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)) returns a single value, so there are no characters that have multiple types according to Java. Thus, there is no character for which `isDigit` and `isLetter` both return true. Likewise, `_` is `CONNECTOR_PUNCTUATION` (easy to see this with a quick sample Java program), which is neither a digit nor a letter.

So this is code by someone who was being overly defensive. `isDigit` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

The sample is doing the job only halve.

It assumes that `Character::isDigit` returns `true` only for the characters '0' to '9', but that is wrong. This also means that the calculation `(int) peek - 48` is not reliable to get the numeric value of the digit.

When the code should really work on any kind of digits, it needs to look like this:

```
final var radix = 10;
var value = 0;
while( Character.isDigit( peek) && ((value = Character.digit( peek, radix )) != -1) ) 
{
  sum = sum * radix + value;
  readch( br );
}
```

To cover also the hex digits from 'A' to 'F' or their lowercase equivalents, just remove the `Character::isDigit` check (and change `radix` accordingly).

Using `Character::getNumericValue` would also get the Roman numbers, but this will not work properly for the calculation of `sum`.